# Winform updates on long running tasks

Tags: c#, winforms, vsto, long-running-processes

Do you have a good solution for keeping a 'Please wait' winform 'painted' while an application is performing a long running task ?

I've tried using form.refresh() on each step, but there are a few long running queries that take place, which means that this isn't frequent enough.

Basically this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148963/keeping-guis-responsive-during-long-running-tasks) but, on C# in Excel through VSTO (rather than Python).

Comment: Is this really web-forms, or is this winforms?  You are talking about Excel and VSTO.  and if it is webforms, you don't have a refresh method.

Comment: Sorry, yes, Winforms, not Webforms.. Have edited the question... It's been a long day...

Comment: Any  final solution with full source code sample? What about using long running process with steps using C#, SignalR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a good example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/prettygoodsplashscreen.aspx) with code in C#.

It is for splash screens specifically, however it is almost identical process (perhaps minus some of the flashy Opacity) to create a Please wait window.

The key information is that you will need a separate thread.  This can complicate things however the article gives a good coverage/example of how to do it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for this link. Works really well, and integrates into my Excel VSTO app really nicely!

Answer (score 3):

As statichippo mentioned, I would use the BackgroundWorker Class. Its purpose is to simplify multi-threading and allow for a worker thread to do the time consuming processing without locking the GUI.

Here is a quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx):

> The BackgroundWorker class allows you
>   to run an operation on a separate,
>   dedicated thread. Time-consuming
>   operations like downloads and database
>   transactions can cause your user
>   interface (UI) to seem as though it
>   has stopped responding while they are
>   running. When you want a responsive UI
>   and you are faced with long delays
>   associated with such operations, the
>   BackgroundWorker class provides a
>   convenient solution.

Here is a good tutorial how to use the BackgroundWorker class in windows forms:   [Implementing multi-threading in WinForms using the BackgroundWorker class](http://fernandof.wordpress.com/2007/04/04/implementing-multi-threading-in-winforms-using-the-backgroundworker-class/)

There are more complicated ways to implement Multi-Threading in C# for complex scenarios but for most simple scenarios the BackgroundWorker works great (for me at least).

Here are some links I pulled from Google on C# Multi Threading:
[MSDN Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28VS.71%29.aspx)
[Introduction to Multithreading in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/MultithreadingIntro10062005000439AM/MultithreadingIntro.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use an asynchronous delegate to show the form on a threadpool thread.

Threads in the threadpool are recommended for shorter lived threads that do not last for the entire application duration.  As this is to display a short-lived please wait window, the threadpool is a reasonable choice.

The Action delegate (.NET 2.0+) is used along with it's BeginInvoke() method to automatically run the delegate code on a threadpool thread.

Some notes:

- It is important to use Control.BeginInvoke for any cross thread GUI calls, such as closing the please wait form in ClosePleaseWait().
- Also, the `m_pleaseWaitForm.ShowDialog();` actually starts a new message loop in the new thread.  This is what keeps the please wait form alive.
- Because a threadpool thread is used, this thread is automatically a background thread and will be terminated if the main application is closed.
- Apart from running on another thread, there is nothing special about Form2.  You can place any child controls such as Pictureboxes, labels etc on it.
- `(MethodInvoker)delegate { ...  }` is just a .NET 2.0 way of running code in a delegate inline.

The example below can be added to a WinForms project containing Form1: the main form, and Form2: the please wait form.

```
   private Form2 m_pleaseWaitForm = null;

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This code could also be placed in eg. a button click event handler.

        Action<Rectangle> a = new Action<Rectangle>(ShowPleaseWait);

        a.BeginInvoke(this.Bounds, null, null);

        // Do your long running tasks

        ClosePleaseWait();
    }


    private void ShowPleaseWait(Rectangle  bounds)
    {
        // This method runs on the new thread.

        m_pleaseWaitForm = new Form2();

        m_pleaseWaitForm.TopMost = true;
        m_pleaseWaitForm.Location = new Point(bounds.Left + bounds.Width / 2 - m_pleaseWaitForm.Width / 2, bounds.Top + bounds.Height / 2 - m_pleaseWaitForm.Height / 2);

        m_pleaseWaitForm.ShowDialog();

    }

    private void ClosePleaseWait()
    {
        m_pleaseWaitForm.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { m_pleaseWaitForm.Close(); });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a BackgroundWorker

Comment: Man I'm tired -- I thought this was winforms.  The answer should be to use AJAX (MS AJAX will work fine).  You can use a Timer control to check the status.  Then you can redirect on completion.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, question was changed from webforms=>winforms.

Comment: I believe statichippo is correct.  Using a backgroundworker thread should do this for you.